# Help show/prove linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help to understand how to prove the two following tasks. Also, I'm having trouble seeing the big difference between the two.

1) Let $n > 0$, and let $L_{n,k}$ be a subspace spanned by the unity-vectors $e_j$, $j = 1,\ldots,k$. Show that there is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ so that $L_{n,k} = \text{Ker}(T)$.

2) Let $H$ be a $k$-dimesional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that there is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ so that $H=\text{Ker}(T)$.

I am completely stuck, so a small hint might not be sufficient, however all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so every vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $\lambda_1 e_1 + ... +\lambda_n e_n$.

What is the easiest way to ensure $e_1,e_2,...,e_k$ are in the kernel (i.e. get mapped to $0$)?

Just chop off the corresponding terms...in other words let $T(v) = \lambda_{k+1}e_{k+1} + ... +\lambda_n e_n$.

You can now show that ker$(T) = L_{n,k}$

Part $2$ is exactly the same just choosing a different basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I am still at a loss. I think it might need to be dumbed down. I am probably overanalyzing it.I am stuck on trying to find a transformation-matrix to multiply L with. Would I be correct if I end up with a ((k+1...n)x(k+1...n))-matrix to represent Ker(T)?

Comment: You don't need to think about matrices, a linear transformation is a map between vector spaces.

Comment: Maybe for part 1 it is easier to understand in terms of coordinates. Any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n)$. The vectors in $L_{n,k}$ are the vectors of the form $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k,0,0,...,0)$. What is the most natural way to go from vectors of this form to zero vectors of length $n-k$?

Comment: To remove the $a_1,...,a_k$ part? I think the problem lies with me not having an intuitive understanding of how the $Ker(T)$, wich is $0$, can be equal to $L_{n,k}$ wich contains $e_j$-vectors, wich contains a $1$. Edit, or wait a minute, does the basis $e_{k+1},...e_{n}$ represent $L_{n,k}$ just aswell as $e_1 ,..., e_k$?

Comment: So we just extend the standard basis up to $e_{n}$, then remove the old part($e_{1},...,e_{k}$), and then $L_{n,k}$ is sort of defined by the space $L_{n,k+1...n}$, and when we transform it to $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, we lose the $1$'s in $e_j,j=k+1,...n$, and we are left with all $0$, wich is equal to $Ker(T)$, wich has the same size as $L_{n,k}$? This has to be right. Please tell me I got it now!

Comment: You are really overcomplicating this. We want a way of starting with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and getting from them vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. But we don't want any old map, we want a linear one...that also sends anything in $L_{n,k}$ to the zero vector and anything else to some non-zero vector.

Comment: Most intuitive map possible would be to write every vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of the $e_i$'s and just chop off those components for $i\leq k$. This certainly leaves you with a vector in the right space...

Comment: Ker(T) is not $0$...it is the things that get mapped to $0$.